# Is it possible to create unwind segues programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

My app has a navigation controller where the first view controller is a login screen and all other screens are pushed on top.

I would like to unwind to the login screen whenever any http request to the backend returns a 401 error.

What I had in mind was to add an extension to the ViewController class with something like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func unwindToLoginScreen() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: loginScreen)
    }
}
```

And the segue would be an unwind segue. Then, whenever the request fails I call the view controller's `unwindToLoginScreen` method.

However, the problem with this approach is that I would have to remember to create said unwind segues on the storyboard for all new view controllers that I added to the project.

So far I think the ideal plan would be to be able to create the unwind segue programatically instead of using the storyboard. So, my `unwindToLoginScreen()` extension method would work in any new view controller by default. Something like:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func unwindToLoginScreen() {
        let segue = UnwindSegue(identifier: "blablah", segue: LoginViewController.unwindToLoginViewController)
        segue.perform()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: It is possible, I've done so in the past. I don't recall how :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create segues in code, but you can pop to the root of the `UINavigationController`'s stack:

```
func returnToLoginScreen() {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If you want to pop to a viewController that isn't the root, you can find it in the array of viewController's managed by the `UINavigationController` and then call `popToViewController`:

```
// pop to second viewController in the stack
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[1], animated: true)
```

... or search for the `ViewController` by type:

```
if let loginVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is LoginViewController }) {
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: this is awesome. And... supposing the view controller isn't exactly the root view controller... can i pop to an arbitrary controller in the stack?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the controller to pop to like this for example: `self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[1], animated: true)`.  This would pop to the second viewController in the stack.

Comment: This helped me a lot!